# Do VxWorks shell scripts support conditional expressions?

Tags: vxworks

Do .vx scripts have any kind of if-else construct? I've been through the documentation and Google, and I've done some experimenting as well, but have come up empty so far.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is absolutely no support for conditionals.